# MySQL many-to-many with id: how to delete all but most recent entry?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables - jobs, and jobEntries

jobEntries has a jobId that maps to jobs, but wasn't set up as an "official" foreign key relationship so I can't use CASCADE DELETE.

For each job, there are many jobEntries.

I want to delete from jobEntries so there is at most one jobEntry for each job, leaving only the most recent jobEntry (ORDER BY createdAt DESC)

I've tried many iterations of nested queries, COUNT(), HAVING, etc. but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

We can ignore the `Jobs` table, since we're only concerned with data in the `jobEntries` table. Thus the `many-to-many` aspect is not relevant.

We need to know what the most recent job entry for each job is, which we can get with a query like this:

```
select jobID, max(createdAt) as maxCreatedAt from jobEntries group by jobID;
```

However, this is not enough. We need to select all the rows where the `createdAt` is not the most recent.

We can do this by joining the `jobEntries` table to the output of the query above, and then deleting all the rows where the `createdAt` column is not the `maxCreatedAt` value for that jobID:

```
delete je from jobEntries as je
  join (select jobID, max(createdAt) as maxCreatedAt from jobEntries group by jobID) as maxJE using(jobId)
  where createdAt <> maxCreatedAt;
```

[DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bh6cb3nRUSRJjFM5i1DS9Q/0)

Answer (score -1):

Well, just FYI I think you couldn't use CASCADE DELETE because 1) you aren't deleting jobs, only JobEntries and 2) You aren't deleting all the JobEntries, only the ones that aren't most recent.

I would encourage you to post your attempts (with Count, Having, etc.) as it would be more instructive for you to learn what mistake you made ... However, be that as it may, here's some solutions. They are written in `SQL Server` syntax, but should be applicable to `MySql` with some appropriate fixes to the sql syntax.

##### Some sample data

```
declare @Job table (JobId int, CreatedAt datetime)
insert into @Job 
values
    (1, '2023-01-01'),
    (2, '2023-01-15'),
    (3, '2023-01-30')

declare @JobEntry table (JobEntryId int, JobId int, CreatedAt datetime)
insert into @JobEntry
values
    (1, 1, '2023-01-01'),
    (2, 1, '2023-01-02'),
    (3, 2, '2023-01-15'),
    (4, 2, '2023-01-16'),
    (5, 2, '2023-01-17')
```

##### Approach 1, with a correlated subquery

```
delete je
from
    @Job j
    inner join @JobEntry je
    on j.JobId = je.JobId
    where je.JobEntryId <> (
    select top (1) je2.JobEntryId 
    from @JobEntry je2 
    where je2.JobId = je.JobId 
    order by je2.CreatedAt desc)
--select * from @JobEntry
```

##### Approach 2, with a CTE

```
;with LastJobEntryCreatedAt as (
    select 
        je.JobId, 
        Max(je.CreatedAt) as CreatedAt
    from @JobEntry je
    group by je.JobId)
delete je
    from @JobEntry je
    left join LastJobEntryCreatedAt le
    on je.JobId = le.JobId
    and je.CreatedAt = le.CreatedAt
    where le.CreatedAt is null
--select * from @JobEntry
```